# Custom Audio Effect in CoreAudio Audio Graph - Render Callback

Tags: iphone, callback, core-audio, effect, audiounit

I'm building a MIDI synth using CoreAudio. Currently, I have the following audio graph:

```
    Sampler -> Reverb -> IO
```

I need to add a chorus effect to the graph as well as the reverb. The problem is that there isn't a chorus effect on the iPhone. To get around this I'm planning to implement my own chorus effect. To do this I need access to the audio stream.

The question is: what's the best way to get access to the audio stream in the middle of the audio graph.

```
    Sampler -> Reverb -> [Custom processing] -> IOUnit
```

Is there a way I can alter the audio stream using something like the AudioUnitAddRenderNotify callback? or do I have to break the audio graph like this:

```
    Sampler -> Reverb -> [AudioUnitAddRenderNotify callback] -> buffer -> [RenderCallback] -> IOUnit
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a render notify callback (`AudioUnitAddRenderNotify`) to your Reverb node's AU and process the audio in the `kAudioUnitRenderAction_PostRender` call.  I did an experiment and got this to work as long as the callback was added after the AUGraph was open, and no processing was done in the prerender call.

Comment: This did work. It turns out that you can modify the audio information on the fly using the render notify.